# Magento: Add Block Before Footer

Tags: magento, content-management-system, block

I'm using GrayScale template, and I want to move the recent viewed to a block before the footer.
I need this block with a different color from footer.
So, I removed this block of page.xml:

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
```

And added to footer block of page.xml:

```
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>
```

Perfect!
But, I need this block before footer and not inside...
How can I do this???

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your Page.xml file and find the following block

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/htmlfooter.phtml">
```

It should be arond line number 100.

Inside the block paste the following code

```
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="reports.product.viewed" as="recently_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>recently_viewed</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</block>
```

The block should look like this
[image]
Now open your footer.phtml file and before the footer, i.e.

```
<div class="footer-container">
```

write the following code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?>
```

And change the child block calling like the following
[image]
Now any logged in user will be able to view their recently viewed product and yes, it is outside the footer.
You can style it according to your needs, and you can also set the column count from the  block itself.
Enjoy.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answear. The recently viewed keep inside the footer. (div class="footer-container")

Comment: You can call the <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('recently_viewed') ?> anywhere you want. you can keep it inside the footer. (div class="footer-container") . And also if you find this answer helpful, then please accept the answer :D

Comment: check the image.. of the footer.phtml that I have posted. you have to change the call of the child blocks, as is shown in the 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this right above the 'footer' section:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="review.before.footer" as="review.before.footer" translate="label">
       <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
</block>
```

Comment: did you refresh cache, if yes are you echoing anything in the template? (maybe the template is working, but the logic is not displaying anything)

Comment: Yes, I disabled cache for testing